# How can I grep same format substrings within a long string by java regular expression?

Tags: java, regex

For example, I want to grep both `/css/screen/shared/styles.css` and `/css/screen/nol/styles.css` from this long string:

```
@import "/css/screen/shared/styles.css";
@import "/css/screen/nol/styles.css";
```

Note that this long string contains 2 lines, it should look like this in java code:

```
String sentence = "@import \"/css/screen/nol/styles.css\";\n@import \"/css/screen/shared/styles.css\";";
```

So far, I have:

```
"@import\\s\"(.*?)\";\n"
```

it only identifies the "/css/screen/shared/styles.css", but ignores the "/css/screen/nol/styles.css".

Here is my code:

```
public static String getImportCSS(String sentence){
        String result = "";
        if(sentence.length() == 0) return null;
        if(sentence.indexOf("@import ") != -1){
            Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("@import\\s\"(.*)\";");
            Matcher regexMatcher = regex.matcher(sentence);
            if(regexMatcher.find()){
                for(int i = 0; i <= regexMatcher.groupCount(); i++){
                    result = regexMatcher.group(1);
                }
            }
            return result;
        }
        return null;
    }
```

What am I doing wrong here? Thanks!

Comment: In what sense are they the same format?

Comment: For each line contains: @import "xxxx/xxxx/xxxx"; and I only need xxxx/xxxx/xxxx.

Comment: please edit your question to add more information.

Comment: Just remove `\n` at the end of the pattern. `"@import\\s*\"(.*?)\";"` is enough.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I tried, but it only identified "/css/screen/shared/styles.css" and ignored "/css/screen/nol/styles.css". i want both of them.

Comment: Show your code then. Using `if` instead of `while` :) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot match the second string because your regex has an LF (`\n`) at the end.

Remove it, and the pattern will find both the strings. However, I'd advise to use a negated character class `[^"]*` (*zero or more characters other than a `"`*) rather than a lazy dot matching since the strings should not contain a double quote:

```
@import\s*\"([^"]*)\";
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/jX6mM5/1)

[Java demo](http://ideone.com/VlC2Nb):

```
String str = "@import \"/css/screen/shared/styles.css\";\n@import \"/css/screen/nol/styles.css\";"; 
Pattern ptrn = Pattern.compile("@import\\s*\"([^\"]*)\";");
Matcher matcher = ptrn.matcher(str);
while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That is perfect.